# how to split an image in to multiple parts 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

how can I slice an image into multiple pieces ? my image size is 300x300 an I want to make 9 pieces of it.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

CWUIKit project available at https://github.com/jayway/CWUIKit has a category on `UIImage` adding a method like this:

```
UIImage* subimage = [originalImage subimageWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

Should be useful for you.