# Xcode split image into 4

Tags: image, split, photo, crop

I would like to allow the user to import an image from their camera roll. Then have my App split the image into 4 equal photos to display on screen. Is this possible?

Comment: As much as I would love to answer this question myself, [your question has already been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014953/how-to-split-an-image-in-to-multiple-parts).

Comment: I looked at the other answer but did not think it solved my problem or else did not understand the answer.

Comment: Found this answer and it worked! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661291/split-uiimage-in-half