# xcode swift how do I split an image?

Tags: xcode, swift, split, imageview

I am working with Swift 2.0 and I would like to split an image into multiple pieces. I know this is a repeat, but they syntax is old and I am having trouble update.

Comment: what did you done so far? any code? what do you mean under `split`? also check:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-a-uiimage/25824454#25824454

Comment: I am trying to learn this before I start my project, but this is the outdated code I have found:
UIImage* subimage = [originalImage subimageWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

Comment: Add additional code and information to the question. What you have is a method call, where did it come from?

Comment: Duplicate of the SO question: [how to crop image in to pieces programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4743242/451475).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but I am having trouble updating the syntax of the method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014953/how-to-split-an-image-in-to-multiple-parts

Comment: As I stated, add *your* code along with what the problem is to the question. SO is not a code writing service, it is here to help developers with their code.

Comment: As I stated, my code will not be helpful in the slightest. If you had read you question, you would realize I am asking for help updating the syntax from a previously asked question not asking for someone to write my application.

Comment: The answer in the question has the code.

Comment: Read the third comment in this chain again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

update: **Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**

You can add this extension to split your images:

```
extension UIImage {
    var topHalf: UIImage? {
        cgImage?.cropping(
            to: CGRect(
                origin: .zero,
                size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height / 2)
            )
        )?.image
    }
    var bottomHalf: UIImage? {
        cgImage?.cropping(
            to: CGRect(
                origin: CGPoint(x: .zero, y: size.height - (size.height/2).rounded()),
                size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height - (size.height/2).rounded())
            )
        )?.image
    }
    var leftHalf: UIImage? {
        cgImage?.cropping(
            to: CGRect(
                origin: .zero,
                size: CGSize(width: size.width/2, height: size.height)
            )
        )?.image
    }
    var rightHalf: UIImage? {
        cgImage?.cropping(
            to: CGRect(
                origin: CGPoint(x: size.width - (size.width/2).rounded(), y: .zero),
                size: CGSize(width: size.width - (size.width/2).rounded(), height: size.height)
            )
        )?.image
    }
}
```

---

```
extension CGImage {
    var image: UIImage { .init(cgImage: self) }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let imgURL = URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imgURL) { data, response, error in
    guard
        let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data)
    else { return }
    
    let topHalf = image.topHalf
    let bottomHalf = image.bottomHalf
    
    let topLeft = topHalf?.leftHalf
    let topRight = topHalf?.rightHalf
    let bottomLeft = bottomHalf?.leftHalf
    let bottomRight = bottomHalf?.rightHalf
}.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am receiving the error UIImage has no member topHalf. Am I applying this code incorrectly? Sorry, I am still very new.

Comment: Just add this extension to your project or playground

Comment: Do I need to add the extension in a specific way? I have not encountered this yet.

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? Like any extension you can just create a new Swift File within your project and drop it there. You might need to add import UIKit instead of import Foundation

Comment: Worked Great! Thank you so much!